# Random Patch extraction (10000)

Tags: image, patch

I am carrying a project on Image compressions. I'm stuck with patch extraction, I'm able extract only one patch from image, 
can anyone code or make an algorithm to extract random infinite patches?

Comment: Hi Krishna. Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Comment: What's the problem? Generate two different random numbers less than the width of the image and two different random numbers less than the height, Now extract the rectangle defined by x1,y1 and x2,y2.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily at the command line with ImageMagick which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for OSX and Windows.

First, make a random image:

```
convert -size 640x480 xc:gray +noise random -resize 32x24 -scale 640x480 -auto-level base.png
```

[image]

Now, extract infinite patches from it - well 10, to be precise but you can change line 3 as you wish!

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get width and height of base image
read w h < <(convert base.png -format "%w %h" info:)

# Generate infinite (well, 10) patches
for ((i=0;i<10;i++)) ; do
   # Generate random top left corner
   ((x=RANDOM % (w-1) ))
   ((y=RANDOM % (h-1) ))

   # Generate random width and height
   ((a=RANDOM % (w-x) ))
   ((b=RANDOM % (h-y) ))
   # DEBUG echo $x,$y,$a,$b
   # Extract patch to file "result-$i.png"
   convert base.png -crop ${a}x${b}+${x}+${y} result-${i}.png
done
```

Here are the generated images:

[image]